# Dilemma in using GenericKeychain in iOS

Tags: ios, security, keychain

I develop mobile payment application. For connection with soap web-service app must save login and sessionID. I store them in CoreData. But this is insecure - everyone can read data from db. I decided to store sensitive data in [Generic Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). Afterwards I understood that I should store a keys from keychain to access and eject login and sessionID from keychain db. What way can I store keys from keychain db? Thanks a lot! P.S. Sorry if my English ugly, it's not my native language.

Comment: please show users what you have tried so far for better answers.

Comment: Checkout the DetailViewController.m from that files, how it uses `objectForKey` to store/retrieve values from the keychain.